# OPTIONS requests from iOS

Tags: linux, django, apache2, ios

I've got a Web app on Django that makes a bunch of asynchronous calls to the server.

It works perfectly well from all browsers except Safari, specifically on iOS where users are reporting at least an intermittent problem.

It seems the problem might stem from Safari sending an `OPTIONS` request. This is a snippet from the Apache log (edited for anonymity):

> 172.31.34.143 - - [20/Jun/2017:14:12:46 +0100] "OPTIONS /asyncservice/ HTTP/1.1" 500 245 "http://www.example.com/app/" "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone;
>   CPU iPhone OS 10_3_2 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/603.2.4 (KHTML, like
>   Gecko) Version/10.0 Mobile/14F89 Safari/602.1"

Has anyone experienced this, and is there a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I may have solved this.

There is a request header set by the JavaScript that sends the Django CRSF ( Cross Site Request Forgery) protection header.

Safari sees this header, doesn't recognise it and sends what is referred to as a preflight request, the OPTIONS request.

Apache refuses this request on the grounds that Safari has not sent the correct origin over with the OPTIONS request (why it doesn't is hazy - it looks to me like a bug in Safari, really.)

Safari gets a 500 and concludes the POST request is fraudulent and refuses to make it.

Given the reason that the request is made is because Safari doesn't recognise the Django CRSF header, allowing Apache to receive from any origin and trusting Django to handle the bad requests with CRSF seems reasonable.

So, I've configured Apache to allow from any origin, like this:

> ```
> Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
> Header add Access-Control-Allow-Headers "origin, x-requested-with, content-type"
> Header add Access-Control-Allow-Methods "PUT, GET, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS"
> ```

So far, none of these 500s since, but its early days.